# How do you add an image to a single specific cell in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, cell

Using C# and Visual Studio, I have a `DataGridView` with 2 columns. For every row, the first column will display text. For every row EXCEPT one specific row, the second column will display text. In one specific cell in the second column, I need to show an image.

For example:

```
Row[0].Cell[0] = "test"  Row [0].Cell[1] = "test"
Row[1].Cell[0] = "test"  Row [1].Cell[1] = "test"
Row[2].Cell[0] = "test"  Row [2].Cell[1] = need to display an image here
Row[3].Cell[0] = "test"  Row [3].Cell[1] = "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to do it but here is a simple example that will set one single cell to show an image:

```
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(someimagefile);

    DataGridViewImageCell iCell = new DataGridViewImageCell();
    iCell.Value = bmp;
    dataGridView1[1, 2] = iCell;
```

Of course any other image source will work as well..

Try not to leak the bitmaps if you change them..