# How can I show pictures in my Datagridview if they are stored as path in MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, image, datagridview, path

I have all the pictures stored as path (ex: m1.png) in MySQL database, my problem is how can I show them in my C# app using datagrid view

```
    public adminPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void adminPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM items";
        command = new MySqlCommand(query, connexion);
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        //filling the datagridview
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 100;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        da.Fill(table);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
   }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You could add an image column to the DataTable, then hide the path column in the DGV.  Use the cellformatting event to load the images as needed.  You may need to do something to dispose of the images later

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: There are so many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834443/how-do-you-add-an-image-to-a-single-specific-cell-in-a-datagridview/38835794#38835794).. - The real question are: Will there be different images? In different cells? With different sizes?

Comment: yes all images are differents but same size , different images paths are stored in image col in items table in mysql db..so every image cell is different in every row in DGV.